# Передать массив чекбоксов в PHP-файл с помощью AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, checkbox

**Форма**

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="dop[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="dop[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="dop[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="dop[]" value="4">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function send()
{
    var name = $('#name').val()
    var surname = $('#surname').val()
    var id_usl = $('#id_usl').val()
    var srok = $('#srok').val()

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SendData.php",
        data: "name="+name+"&surname="+surname+"&id_usl="+id_usl+"&srok="+srok,

        success: function(html) {
            $("#result").empty();
            $("#result").append(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Как отправить в `SendData.php` массив `value` выделенных чекбоксов и как прочитать его в php-файле?

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы в файле SendData.php в переменную $dop_usl записался массив вида {2,4} (если были отмечены 2й и 4й чекбокс, соответственно.) ($dop_usl=$_POST['dop']). Что именно надо дописать в JS-файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом .serialize()

Например:

```
function send()
{
    var name = $('#name').val()
    var surname = $('#surname').val()
    var id_usl = $('#id_usl').val()
    var srok = $('#srok').val()

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SendData.php",
        data: {inputs: $('form').serialize()},

        success: function(html) {
            $("#result").empty();
            $("#result").append(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Как прочесть данные?

Для начала выполите:

```
parse_str($_POST['inputs'], $inputs);
```

Затем:

```
print_r($inputs);
```